# Fix PDF with unreadable characters

Tags: pdf, ghostscript

Example PDF page: https://db.tt/qRcF000k

This is sample page from a document, where copied text shows as question marks in my favorite reader SumatraPDF (mupdf) just the same as in Adobe Acrobat. But my main problem is that I can not search this document because of this, nor I can index it.

OTOH, xpdf's `pdftotext` extracts correct text.
In Adobe Acrobat if I use "Copy as formatted text", correct text is written to clipboard, although I still can't search from Acrobat.
Also if I open the linked page in Firefox's built-in PDF reader I can correctly copy the text.

Can GhostScript perhaps be instructed to correct this issue, which I can not describe differently then as 'unreadable characters'?

Answer (score 1):

The PDF file uses subset fonts with non-standard Encodings and no ToUnicode CMaps. So no, you can't have Ghostscript 'correct' this file.

In fact I can't see how anything can possibly be extracting sensible text from this, and indeed my version of Acrobat (Pro X and Reader XI) can't copy meaningful text and don't appear to have a 'copy as formatted text' menu item, can you tell me where to find this ?

However, I notice that the PDF file has actually been created by Ghostscript (version 9.14) so possibly you mean 'starting with a different input file, which I haven't given you, could I have generated a PDF file where the text could be copied', to which I can only say 'I don't know', it depends what was in the original input file .

Comment: *I can't see how anything can possibly be extracting sensible text from this* - you can't by using 'official' information, neither in the PDF structure (as outlined in section *9.10 Extraction of Text Content* of [ISO 32000-1](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf)) nor in the font file itself (no standard names, no mapping to Unicode). An educated guess is possible, though, as the (non-standard) names for the font characters (`C65`, `C66`, ...) contain the ASCII code of the respective character (for characters from the ASCII range, that is).

Comment: Thanks @KenS, here is link to extracted page from original document: [sample_page2.pdf](https://db.tt/OASKBSC3). "Copy with Formatting" command appears as [context menu](http://i.imgur.com/tGjeTkH.png) on selected text in Acrobat XI, maybe it isn't available in Acrobat X.

Comment: Well that's a new one on me :-) It is available in Acrobat X, but I've never noticed it. I have to guess that Acrobat is looking at the glyph names (eg /C65) and deciding that the numeric portion of the glyph name is an ASCII (or possibly UTF8) character code, just as mkl says above. This is a heuristic, of course, and fairly likely to fail. My answer still stands though, Ghostscript cannot 'correct' this file. To do so it would have to either re-encode the font (which we try hard not to do) and then lie about the Encoding, or invent a ToUnicode. Both are a really bad idea.